# What am I doing wrong with my TortoiseSVN merges?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have been having a problem merging a production revision (which required a manual merge to resolve conflicts with an earlier revision) back into the branch where it came from. Merge isn't finding any conflicts and the auto-merge is mangling the merged file. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the SVN setup where I work:

- Trunk is production code, it is auto-deployed to the webserver and can never have any errors or problems.
- "Dev" is a branch where everyone works on general bugfixes and most small development.
- There are other branches for larger projects, eg "project1".
- Every day, Trunk (production) is merged into every single branch, including Dev.  This is because we want no one working on a code base that could be in any way different from our production code with the exception of the changes they've been making in that branch.

(I also welcome criticism of our SVN structure/procedures.)

Note: This is for a large web application that has no concurrently maintained versions, it's just running 24/7 and we constantly are modifying/updating it with bugfixes, new features, etc.

We used to be running into problems with merges daily, and have recently restructured our SVN practices to what I described above. It has seemed problem-free until this happened.

When people have changes that are fully tested and ready to be deployed to production, they merge those revisions from their branch into production.  This often ends up resulting in back-merging of changes from trunk into the branch where they came from later in the day. I assume this could be where the problem is coming from, but it's worked smoothly for weeks until today.

---

**Here are the full details of the situation I'm experiencing:**

A developer is working in Dev and has several revisions they're ready to deploy to production (trunk), they switch to trunk, open the merge dialog, select their branch, cherry pick the few revisions they're planning to deploy, and hit merge (with the default settings). Assuming no conflicts, they would normally commit to trunk (which auto-deploys to the webserver and goes live within seconds). In this case, there is a conflict. Someone else   has previously deployed a revision to trunk that modified one of the same files.  The developer manually merges the two revisions and tests the file, confirms it is working, and commits the merged changes to trunk.

At the end of the day, I merge trunk back into all of our branches to make sure that tomorrow everyone has the latest code and becomes aware of any conflicts sooner rather than later.  To do this I switch to each branch one at a time, open merge, select trunk, and select just the revisions that were committed today to merge. I run the merge with default settings, and commit the merged changes into the branch.  In this case, when I get to the Dev branch, and merge from trunk, I run into problems. Almost all of today's changes in trunk actually came from the Dev branch, so nothing but property modifications get brought in, except for that one file that had the merge conflict when the developer attempted to deploy it. That file gets auto-merged. I open the file to see what it brought in, and the merge is horribly screwed up. It has duplicated some lines of code (resulting in code errors), and placed others out of order, etc.

---

It should also be noted that some of our team uses AnkhSVN in Visual Studio, while I and some others use nothing but TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow-up to @Travis "Merge back ASAP" (+1 from me)

1. GUI-merge for everyday sync-merges is **BAD IDEA (tm)** - "GUI can not be automated"
2. Cherry-pick merges for merges `trunk -> branch` is **BAD IDEA (tm)** - because it *pure sync merge* (`svn help merge` 1-st form) and must be performed this way and rely on mergeinfo only (and have zero chances to have missed records)
3. You (or "merge-master") **must** verify all branches or at least DEV for skipped trunk-revisions (`svn mergeinfo --show-revs=eligible ^/trunk ^/DEV` must me empty)
4. If you SVN-clients still older than 1.8 - step up and use this version: it will not eliminate all merge-hell, but make some sides easier

For your "Merge-dance" development using VCS with merge as first-class citizen (which is still not true for Subversion) will make life a lot easier with a significantly less headaches or ordinary operations: no more "Merge Hell". With SVN-background, migration to Mercurial (**not** Git) will be almost transparent with minimal changes in workflow (in publish and deploy stages)

Comment: I apologize, I feel like you're really helping me out here but I'm having a hard time understanding a couple of things you have said. For instance "because it pure sync merge (svn help merge 1-st form) and must be performed this way and rely on mergeinfo only" 

Also, "using VCS with merge as first-class citizen". 

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The reason that I "cherry pick" for merges from trunk->branch is because before we switched to our current policy, people were cherry picking for trunk->branch and leaving out some revisions entirely, this led to a state of the SVN repo in which I could not merge all revisions, as it would cause hundreds and hundreds of conflicts and often times would fail to merge completely.  So ever since we started this new policy, I pick 100% of the revisions that have been committed to trunk since the last daily sync (yesterday), and make sure they get merged back into branches.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the developer needs to merge trunk into their branch before attempting to deploy their changes.  You say that you do this manually once per day, but it should happen before anyone attempts to deploy to trunk so they are fully up-to-date.

In my experience, I've found that before merging any branch to trunk it is a good idea to merge trunk to that branch first in order to work out the conflicts.

I also generally don't permanently work out of a branch.  My team usually does this:

1. Create a branch off of trunk to work on a particular task
2. Commit the work to the branch
3. Code review the branch
4. Fix anything found in code review and review again
5. Repeat 3 and 4 as necessary
6. Merge trunk into branch to get any completed work since branch and work out conflicts
7. Finally, reintegrate branch into trunk

As a side note, I think in Git you can use a feature called "rebase" that will do the work you do every night (merging trunk into everyone's branch).  I think it actually reorders the commits to make it like your branch actually branched after the new commits in trunk.  Might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree with you on the merge from trunk prior to commit. This is actually listed in our SVN guidelines for the team, and for the most part people do it. In this particular case I'm a little perplexed as the revision that caused the problem was committed to trunk a week ago. This means I've merged trunk back into that branch numerous times since the change was made, but somehow the change never actually made it into the branch. I'm wondering now if maybe I botched the merge without realizing it somehow.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for how to fix the files? Trunk contains the correct version of the code and the development branch does not, however I can't merge from trunk back into the development branch now as it mangles the code. [Edit: I'm definitely interested in GIT but I'm not sure it's something I can convince the team to switch to any time soon.]

Comment: One more comment, since the character limit is fairly low:  In regards to you not generally working permanently out of a branch, I think that's a good way to go. The recent re-structuring of our policies dictates that we delete a branch for a specific project after the final changes are merged into trunk, and if that project ever needs to be worked on again we create a new branch for it fresh from trunk. With the general Dev branch, I don't see a way to do this unless we just arbitrarily reintegrate and then re-create the branch at regular intervals, as general maintenance never ends.

Comment: This is a confusing problem you have here.  Sometimes I have noticed that in cases like this my working copy was messed up, and to fix that I have done a new checkout to try again.  That's a long shot guess, but it may help.  Other than that, perhaps you can try branching from the new trunk and making the edits in a new branch?  I know that's not ideal since your branch history would be different, but it may reveal some of the problem.

Comment: To your one more comment:  It sounds like a similar situation we have in that we develop in a branch, merge it to trunk, then delete the branch.  We do have some permanent branches, though.  Whenever we create a stable release of the software we make a branch at that point.  This way, if any issues arise, we can fix the bug in the branch and merge the bug fix into trunk.  All the while, normal development can continue on the trunk without affecting the stable release branch.  Through years of puzzling merge problems as you have described, we just decided that merging is strictly branch->trunk.

Comment: As for moving to Git, it's not that difficult, and there are ways to keep all your history.  It will just be a slight culture change and probably shouldn't be done unless you have time to get used to it.

Comment: Side-note: suggesting Git to poor SVN-boys is **BAD IDEA (tm)** - it make life even worse for a long time (even not forever)